# Create an event between user controls in WPF without using the constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, events

So i need to call an event from one user control to do things in another. But to do that I would need to create an object in the control that subscribes to the event. Is there a way to do it without having an object?

Some xaml code.

This is in the control that needs to subscribe and change. Selector is a custom listbox with some styles.

```
<switch:Selector x:Name="ConfigSelector" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" SelectedConfigurationChangedEvent="SelectedConfigurationChangedEventOccured"></switch:Selector>
```

This is a button that should call an event and do things with the listbox showen previously in another user control.

```
<Button Name="button" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Width="80" Padding="5,3" Margin="10,10,0,10" Content="Example" Click="OnButtonClick"></Button>
```

Comment: I think it is possible. If you put a `Button` in a `UserControl` it is also possible to change the layout of that button without writing any event code. Therefore, I think it must also be possible with your UserControl. You can probably do it by means of `Triggers`. But can you show some XAML code?

Comment: Have you tried using Commands? this seems like a good candidate for a RoutedCommand

Comment: just added some code

Comment: @ShayD RoutedCommand did work. Thanks :) Post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to use Commands, they are the primae candidate for this in WPF

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, for example if you want to change the content of button when the property of another button got changed , you can do this without having an object using Trigger:

Like In this example i am changing the content of one button on changed of IsEnabled property of another button.

```
<Button >
<Button.Style>
<Style.Triggers>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=AnotherButtonName , Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False">
<Setter Property="Content" Value="Hi Hello"/>
</Style.Triggers>
</Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Might be it helps you.

Comment: But that only works if both buttons are in the same user control right? What if they are in different ones?

Answer (score 0):

You have to *expose* that functionality of `UserControl`

Something like (dependency property):

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl),
        new PropertyMetadata((d, a) => ((MyUserControl)d).TextChanged()));

    private void TextChanged()
    {
        someTextBlock.Text = Text;
    }
}
```

Now you can bind something to `someTextBlock.Text` in the window where `MyUserControl` is used, by using `MyUserControl.Text`.